# How can I keep /home when reinstalling?

Tags: system-installation

More than a year ago I have installed 10.04, then I upgraded many times (10.04 -> 12.04 -> 13.04 -> 13.10) and during my first year with Linux I have installed lots of junk apps, changed the desktop environment a few times and now my OS seems to be very slow and I have many bugs, too.

The problem is that it's a bit difficult to format everything because I have a Windows partition and there are some important things there, my /home folder also contains important files.

So, is there a fast way to install 13.10, removing all old apps, dependencies and scripts, but without affecting either the windows partition or my /home folder?

Comment: if your /home folder is on the same partition with the root directory, then you cann't.

Comment: Ok, and If I just backup /home somewhere, can I install 13.10 without formatting Windows partition?

Comment: @sqx1 That's not true. You can in fact reinstall root without reformatting /home on the same partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Considering your set up. I would back up my home folder first.

Start new blank installation, on screen where system is asking to where to install Ubuntu choose `something else,`

[image: ubuntu installation screenshoot]

than in new screen that pops up chose partition and mount point for your Ubuntu partition and install fresh copy of Ubuntu. 
Remaining partitions will remain untouched. When installation finalized use your backup to return important files in your home directory

As always when playing with partitions **make good backup** of all important files on Windows and Ubuntu partition, just in case. I mostly have everything important backed up in at least 2 different external HDD.

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact possible to install 13.10, removing all old apps, dependencies and scripts (scripts not in `/home` that is), but without affecting either the windows partition or `/home`.

1. First, as everyone says, back up your data (documents, photos, etc). I wouldn't bother to back up hidden configuration files in your `/home` since you want to reset all of that anyway.
2. Use `sudo blkid` or `gparted` to be sure you know what partitions contain `/` and Windows. Look for recovery or other Windows partitions that you may need to be sure are kept. Write it all down.
3. Do *not* choose the option to *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7*. You want the option that says *Something else*.
4. You will then enter the partitioner. Choose to mount the partition that contains root as `/`, but (cue the ominous music)...*do not check the box to format the partition*.
5. Not formatting the partion to be mounted as `/` is the key part. If you do not format the partition it will not overwrite `/home`.

That said, it may be better - after backing up - to just reformat the drive and do a clean install anyway.

You have been good about updating, and each update should reconfigure various config files hidden in `/home` as needed, so there shouldn't be any hidden time bombs from bad/old config files hanging around.

But your stated concern is speed and general clunkiness. Why risk ending up with the same problems from a hard to debug config issue?

I would also recommend using *Something else* to do this (but now checking the box to reformat `/`). The option to *Install alongside* works well in most cases, but it takes the control away from you and lets the installer make the decisions. This is especially a potential problem if you have Windows data or recovery partitions to preserve.