# Is there a way to upgrade from a CD?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 14.10

Is there a way to upgrade Ubuntu from a CD rather than across the network? As it stands now the only thing I know how to do from a CD is a clean install, which wipes everything on the partition.

Comment: A fresh install does NOT wipe /home , separate partition or not. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 14.04 .iso now has an "upgrade existing" option. However, it still requires a network connection.

Always backup your files. Also, as far as I know, you will keep all the stuff in your home folder so that includes allot of your settings but you might need to reinstall some of the non standard apps.

I just checked out 14.10 studio and didn't see that option, however, all you have to do is choose "something else". Then, select the Ubuntu partition, select ext4, mount point "/" and DO NOT place a check mark to format the partition. By NOT formating the partition, the installation will not wipe your /home folder.