# How to install Audacity

Tags: 13.10, tar

First of all, I'm new to Ubuntu. I just install it. I do not know anything about linux though I'm a Windows user. I'm trying to install Audacity in the software center but always fails. First, it says that it requires a trusted package. I hit OK and this repeats like 8 times. Then, it just stops. I downloaded the TAR.XZ from the Audacity page, extracted it but... It seems really complicated to install via Terminal, no clear instructions anywhere... Can't I drag an "install" file or similar in Terminal?

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install audacity` in a terminal and post the error message(s) you get

Comment: Thanks for tue quick answer.  There were various errors... I'll post it one by one.

Comment: So did that work ? or did you get an error ?

Comment: First, 
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libflac++6 libportsmf0 libsbsms10 libsoxr0 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0
  libvamp-hostsdk3 audacity-data libid3tag0 audacity
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? ^Crpo@rafael-Laptop:~$ y
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.3.2 final 0
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 13.10
Release: 13.10
Codename: saucy

Comment: And then this

unsupported locale setting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 24, in crash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 69, in main
    enable_i18n()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 40, in enable_i18n
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/locale.py", line 541, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Comment: You are running Ubuntu 13.10 which is beyond end of life and thus no longer supported. I suggest you install or upgrade to a supported version of ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out... Thanks a lot! One last thing, ¡if I download the latest version of Ubuntu, it will "overwrite" the version that I have?

Comment: yes, you can preserve your data in your home directory if you DO NOT format it.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation and http://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you upgrade to a Ubuntu Trusty Tahr and install Audacity. Procedure:

1. Switch on your computer.
2. Press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up the Grub menu.
3. Select `Advanced options`.
4. Select the last option ending with `(recovery mode)`.
5. A recovery kernel will load. It can take up to a few minutes (depends of your hardware)
6. Your PC should display a menu with a number of options.
7. Select `Drop to root shell prompt`.
8. In the prompt, run:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   mount --all
   nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
9. A file will open up. Delete it's content.
10. Paste the following:

    ```
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
    # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
    # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
    # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
    deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
    # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
    deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
    # deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe multiverse restricted main
    ```

    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, paste text. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.
11. Run these commands at the prompt:

    ```
    apt-get update
    apt-get dist-upgrade
    apt-get -f install
    dpkg --configure -a
    apt-get autoremove
    apt-get install audacity
    apt-get clean
    reboot
    ```

Comment: Is neccessary to change the `sources.list` file? I think that it's a pain to type all these lines (as without X started the clipboard doesn't work).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm now going to reinstall the latest Ubuntu.

Comment: @Helio: Change it before restarting.