# How to restore lib folder?

Tags: 14.04, restore

Accidentally I removed lib and tmp folders.

```
sudo rm -rf /lib
sudo rm -rf /tmp
```

Is there any way how I can restore `/lib` folder?

I thought that I can create '/lib' folder manually, find at internet ubuntu lib folder and upload it there, but:

```
$ mkdir
$ bash: /bin/mkdir: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a backup you have virtually no chance. The effort is not worth it. Re-install your system and avoid these actions in the future. Linux is robust, but Linux forgives mistakes very rarely.

- `/lib` – Essential libraries for the binaries in `/bin` and `/sbin`
- `/bin` – Essential command binaries that need to be available in single user mode
- `/sbin` – Essential system binaries

---

Read this:

[Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](https://askubuntu.com/q/269880/367165)

[What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](https://askubuntu.com/q/569679/367165)

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.*

Comment: maybe copy it somehow, and create lib folder? won't work?

Comment: A new installation is done in 20 minutes without loosing your data in your `home` folder. http://askubuntu.com/q/269880/367165

Comment: Is there any way to create bootable usb on such system?

Comment: The thing is, you cannot access *any* programs anymore, hence you cannot even donwload an iso file, not speaking of creating a usb. Just reinstall and avoid doing `rm -rf ` anywhere close to root directory

Answer (score 0):

Okay, We can boot live ubuntu and copy that live boot lib folder to your os folder

liveOS: /usr /lib to YourOS: /usr /lib

now may be your OS will boot perfectly but your application can't
so that run [this script](https://makandracards.com/Recruitbot/19505-force-reinstall-of-all-ubuntu-packages) as per instruction

1. sudo apt-get clean
2. paste below into reinstall_all.sh

   #!/bin/bash
   for pkg in `dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v '(dpkg|apt|mysql|mythtv)'` ; do apt-get -y --force-yes install --reinstall $pkg ; done
3. sudo chown root:root reinstall_all.sh
4. sudo chmod 755 reinstall_all.sh
5. sudo ./reinstall_all.sh

this method will take too much time and internet depend on packages which you instlled in past.
sorry for bin