# install ubuntu without ecrase

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

Hello everyone I want to reinstall ubuntu without removing the existing system or my file and documents. That is what I must do aue. [look at this picture to understand me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGmlc.jpg). Thanks for helping me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](http://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder)

Answer (score 0):

It should say to you to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, but for some reason it does not. 
But there is a workaround around your situation. Go to something else. Then you must know which partitions are your Windows partitions.(You will probably have a 100mb Windows system aprtition, and one or two other Windows partitions, However instead of C or D it will be called something like SDA1, SDA2, SDA3, ...)

After that you will need to make a partition for Ubuntu. You should create a partition for Ubuntu from unpartitioned space on your hard drive if possible. If not you should either shrink your existing NTFS(Windows) partitions or you should reformat one of your NTFS partition into EXT4(but this will erase all your data on that partition). Tell the program to use that partition as / .
Either way after you have created an EXT4 partition you just select that partition and tell the installer to install the system on it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot