# Installing Lubuntu over ubuntu and keep all data

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, lubuntu

I have an old pc I've installed ubuntu 16.04 just for fun, my main distro is Lubuntu.

I've done many changes including system files. I know that, if I just install lubuntu over ubuntu system changes will disappear. I'm okay with it, but I want to keep my personal data. Will they be saved? How can I keep them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder)

Answer (score 3):

**Note: Always make a backup before messing with your system!**

You should be able to do this with:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-desktop
```

This should install `lxde`.

At the login screen, you should have a settings wheel then next to the password input, where you can pick LXDE as desktop environment. If you login, your desktop environment should be the selected one. You can also log out and switch to another environment.

Wait for other replies, since I haven't done this before. I hope you get the idea.

**Edit:**
Misunderstood your question. Take a look at `/home/your-user-name/`, this is where your files are stored.

There shouldn't be any files regarding any desktop environments, these are stored somewhere else. So your files will still be around, so you can install multiple other desktop environments to test out or work with with no affect on your personal files.

Comment: Your 2nd edit would be better placed in bold on top of your answer :)

Comment: good input, fixeed ;)

Comment: This is still not my answer. You just show me the way to install lxde. I want lubuntu, without losing data.

Comment: Did you read the last part of my post(the edit)? Or don't you understand? Did you edit system files regarding the display manager?

Comment: I agree this answer is too confusing. `lubuntu-desktop` is LXDE with a *lot* of extras. To install just LXDE and allow logging in and out of it, you could just do  `sudo apt-get install lxsession lxsession-logout`. `lubuntu-desktop` depends on these, and on a lot more, such as XFCE.