# Bad update reinstall ubuntu keep home

Tags: home-directory, reinstall

I know this question is duplicated  but I tried to follow old answers and didn't understanded them.

So I tried to update an it went wrong and now I have to reinstall ubuntu but I would like to keep the home files. I'm a complete beginner at upuntu and not so good with computers so if the answer could be very detailed and best with photos that would be awsome.

When I installed  I think I tried to make a partition  of the `/home` but trying to reinstall I didn't find it.

So when I reinstall and click on do something else I have `/dev/sd1` type ext4 used 26GB with ubuntu 16.04. LST system
`/dev/sd5` type swap used 0 mb
`/dev/sd6` type ext4 used 365 GB

I need to know when I click on change what to do with everyone of them I'm details  because I didn't understand when I read the ubuntu guide to reinstalling.

Please answer with the most basic and detailed instructions possible

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880), it might be just what you're looking for.

---

Boot up a live cd or usb, and go into try ubuntu mode. Open file explorer, and see if you can find your Ubuntu partition. If you can't find it, open a terminal by pressing Ctr-Alt-T on your keyboard and type in:

```
sudo su
gparted
```

In the window that opens up, find your hard drive, and note its `/dev/sdX`. The `X` here is for example, you have to replace it with whatever lowercase letter you got when you found the drive in gparted. Then, in the terminal, run this:

```
mkdir /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu
mount /dev/sdX1 /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu
nautilus /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu
```

Remember to replace `X` with the appropriate letter.

These commands mount your Ubuntu partition so you can view the files. Now you should have a file explorer window open with the root directory of your Ubuntu installation open. Open the folder `home`, and go into your user folder. Now you can plug in a backup drive and copy all the files over. Then when you install Ubuntu again, you can copy the files over.

If you don't see a `home` directory in the folder you opened, then probably `/home` was located on `/dev/sdX6`. In that case, can mount it by typing the same commands above but replacing `/dev/sdX1` with `/dev/sdX6` and `/media/ubuntu/Ubuntu` with `/media/ubuntu/Home`. It's always good to make backups.

If `/dev/sdX6` is the `home` partition, you can do a reinstall without wiping it. Start the install by clicking the Start Install icon on the Desktop, and once you get to the Something Else screen designate `/home` to be on `/dev/sdX6`. Just don't format the partition! If you do, you will lose all your files.

---

But first, what's wrong with your computer? Does it turn on? What do you see? Do you get an error message? Do you get to the [grub menu](https://cdn.pcsteps.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Change-GRUB-boot-order-in-Linux-Mint-Ubuntu-06.png)? Do you get to the [startup screen](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ubuntu-boot-flash-screen.jpg)?

Most of the time, you can repair the installation without having to reinstall. To help us help you better, could you edit your question or reply to this answer explaining exactly what the problem is.