# After upgrade, Ubuntu boots to text console only

Tags: password, gui, console, text

I updated my Ubuntu version to 16.04.01. I restarted the PC but it goes to the text console. It asks for username + password but it does not recognize either of them. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> but it does not show the GUI. It is not responding to sudo, either.

How can I get the GUI back?

Comment: If this happened to me, I would re-install Ubuntu 16.04 **over** my current installation. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/270045/566987)'s something to get you started (a clean install is not what you want).

Comment: You won't be able to do much with your current installationi if you can't login. As that is the case you may wish to review http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password or simply take @Dev advice if you don't mind starting over.

Comment: It's easy enough to re-install Ubuntu, bringing back the GUI and allowing him to login with the password that should not have changed since it (assumption) worked last time, when he _did_ have the GUI.