# reinstall Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I had Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 on my laptop. I upgraded the Ubuntu to 16.04, but it is not working fine. Instead of fixing everything in this installation, is there a way to reset everything in Ubuntu to have like a fresh installation of 16.04, and keep my home folder and also the Windows on the laptop? If not, can I reset as many packages as possible to 16.04 default ones?

The home partition is different from the Ubuntu system partition.

Comment: Windows will stay anyway as long as you choose the correct partition during the installation of Ubuntu. You could just make a backup of your home folder, do a complete new install and copy your backed up home in.

Comment: Download and install https://github.com/gaining/Resetter to reset your apps or ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried [Resetter](https://github.com/gaining/Resetter) for your exact issue. If you haven't modified system files yourself which causes problems and just use the automatic reset and it'll take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the necessary knowledge:
https://askubuntu.com/a/270045/752939

If you have a dedicated partition for /home:

launch the installer
when it comes to the choice of disk and partitions, choose "other" and then, manually select the partition for / and /home; check that the installer will format only the / partition, and not the /home

Comment: I have tried Resetter. If the issues remain, I will use this idea.