# Upgrading to 18.04 from 14.04 but formating only root

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, 18.04

I've dual boot setting with ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 10. Now, I want to do a fresh install 18.04 LTS in the ubuntu partition using live USB. I wonder whether it is possible to retain the home directory as it is. To sum up, the goal is to format and re-install the root for Ubuntu 18.04, while keeping the home directory as it is.

Moreover, it should be compatible with new proposed changes in the drop box as well. I've heard that now dropbox folder should be located in the root.

Comment: Easy if `/home` is a different partition. If not, just select `/` but do not format. Now, what you want to do is not really recommended because some old settings may create problems (and there are huge differences between 14.0 and 18.04, not only a very different desktop environment but that alone can be problematic). Regarding Dropbox I don't know much except that the synced folder can't be in encrypted partitions and now they require EXT4 for Linux and NTFS for Windows but this is not the same as *should be located in the root* which makes no sense.

Comment: Upgrade or fresh install? Which is it?

Comment: So I'm recommended to do a fresh install with formating the entire partition. I'll do that. Thanks for the suggestions. Do I have to worry about the grub setting or the older setting will also serve the purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder)