# Cannot log in to Ubuntu after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, boot, dual-boot, upgrade

I am using a dual boot on a Dell laptop with both Windows and Ubuntu installed, I recently upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and it seemed fine. I was asked to restart the system after the update. However, when restarting, after 1 hour, it was only showing the Ubuntu logo. I decided to power off my laptop, When I turned it on, now I am only seeing a blank and purple screen flicking. And something like `/dev/`.... Flicking every now and then. I can't access the log in page. Can anyone help me as to what to do, I'd appreciate an detailed help.

**EDIT**: I can access recovery mode, Is there anything I should try there?

After reading around, it is recommended to reinstall Ubuntu, However, when I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, I do not have the option to reinstall it while preserving my files in the home directory. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder)