# Ubuntu 18.04 black screen after Plank install

Tags: boot, system-installation, software-installation, screen, plank

My ubuntu installation was working perceftly just until now. I installed plank and added it to my startup applications. I rebooted to make sure plank was working properly and thats when problems started to occur. After reboot my laptop booted into what seemed like a fresh installation of ubuntu with some of my changes (wallpaper, icon theme, cursor theme) still working. I removed plank and rebooted and thats when I was met with the black screen I so despise.

Did anybody have a similar experience? Is it fixable or should I just do a fresh install? Also, is there a way to install ubuntu without losing the contents of my home folder?

Thanks for the help in advdance!

Answer (score 0):

For the third question about installing without losing the contents of the home folder:

The answer appears to be here:

[Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder)

From my perspective, I would just re-install Ubuntu.

Also, if your home folder is not encrypted, you can access it with a live USB and transfer all the files to another USB (requires two free USB ports). This would be best to do even if following the method linked above, just in case. If it is encrypted, it's a bit more of a process, but still possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to resotre GRUB menu options first with live USB and try to run Ubuntu in safemode without desktop GUI. Try to deinstall plank software with apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get remove plank
```

Comment: I immediately tried to remove plank with purge, remove, autoremove, however nothing seemed to help and I reinstalled instead. Thanks for the answer though!