# Trying to set up Dual Boot in Omen 15 laptop with two different SSDs. GRUB does not show up after installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb-drive

I installed a second SSD in my Omen 15 laptop (model 15ek-0012la) looking to set up a dual boot with Ubuntu. I created the Ubuntu flash boot USB (using Balena Etcher), went through the process choosing the second SSD for formatting and, after installation were complete and asked me to reboot the system, the GRUB just didn't load and went straight up to Windows.

After loading up the USB flash drive again and choosing trial, got the following table partition:

[image: Table partition]

Any advice on how to get the GRUB to load on startup?

EDIT: here's the output of parted -l. I chose to ignore attempts to fix for the moment.

[sudo parted -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtKms.png)

Comment: Need a lot more info than that. Start by running `sudo parted -l`  and output that into your question instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot) (Try this link first.) and [Erased Partition and Cannot Boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1378637/) (If the first link doesn't work try steps 3-6.)

Comment: Many HP even new, need UEFI update and SSD firmware update. Check that you have latest revisions. Grub uses efibootmgr to reset boot order, but every question with HP seems to show efibootmgr does not work with HP. But users are able to go into UEFI settings (not the UEFI boot menu) and change boot  order there.

Comment: That's not the full output. You said you booted to Windows, but there's no sign of Windows from that output. Run `sudo parted -l` from Live Ubuntu, then copy and paste all output into your question and put code sample quotes - click the icon { } around highlighted output.