# I installed Ubuntu on ZFS. How do I reinstall while keeping /home intact?

Tags: zfs

So a Ubuntu on ZFS installation will use a whole disk and keep /home in that same disk, while traditionally we can partition the disk and mount /home to a separate partition such that reinstall will not wipe out personal data. Using Ubuntu installation ISO to reinstall a Ubuntu on ZFS system, I don't see an option to reinstall the system but keep /home intact. The obvious but laborious solution is to backup /home and then restore it, but I'm looking for a more novel solution.

Comment: There are deeper questions here you're not going into. The key one is: why do you want to reinstall, not simply upgrade?

Comment: Imagine the system become broken after an upgrade, just for example @LiamProven
Anyway, your comment is not exactly the answer I am looking for.

Comment: It wasn't an answer, because you do not pose a clear question. Anyway: it has been standard behaviour on Ubuntu for a decade or more that if you install on top of an existing installation, it leaves `/home` and some other config directories, and just erases the old OS binaries. Perhaps this applies to ZFS as well. Try it in a VM and see?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder)