# Shutdown freezes on Ubuntu logo

Tags: boot, shutdown

Since two days ago the shutdown of my laptop doesn't work anymore. It freezes on the last screen that shows the Ubuntu logo and then my laptop starts working really hard, gets hot and the cooler is going crazy.

I pressed F1 to see what's happening in the background, but it doesn't help me because I have little knowledge about Linux.

After pressing F1 my computer gets stuck at a black screen with the following text:

```
[2454.246223] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: Controller not ready at resume -19
[2454.246280] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: PCI post-resume error -19!
[2454.246297] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[2454.396556] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
```

Comment: It could either be a hardware issue or a driver issue.

Comment: I think it's fine to just switch off the computer at this point.  Perhaps a later update will remove the problem, but trying to solve it isn't (in my opinion) worth your time.

Comment: @Ray The problem is that the computer is not shutting down properly. This is made explicit in the 2nd line of the shutdown messages. If this is caused by a software issue it would be better to reinstall Ubuntu than to keep on repeatedly manually shutting down the computer by holding down the power button.

Comment: @karel I understand what was posted.  But I don't agree with your assessment.  **Please** don't assume that just because I disagree with your opinion that I am unable to read.  I find that tone very insulting, especially the way you phrased it.  My point is that yes, it could be a software issue.  However, the computer has proceeded to shut down and most of the "danger" of hitting the power button has passed.  i.e., drives might have been unmounted already, etc.  Forcefully switching the power off at this point is not as bad as if a program is running.

Comment: @karel A forum such as this allows many people to offer their own opinions to solve problems.  But please don't assume that just because someone disagrees with you, that they cannot read.  **I** have had these problems before.  I switched off the computer forcefully.  And, weeks or months later, when there was a kernel upgrade, etc. the problem resolved itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the computer is not shutting down properly. This is made explicit in the 2nd line of the shutdown messages. If this is caused by a software issue it would be better to reinstall Ubuntu than to keep on repeatedly manually shutting down the computer by holding down the power button.

Reinstalling Ubuntu would only make sense if you can prove that this freezing during shutdown is a software issue, not a hardware issue. If this problem doesn't occur when running an Ubuntu live session from the Ubuntu live USB that you used to install Ubuntu this would indicate that reinstalling Ubuntu would indeed solve the problem.

Comment: Is there an easy way to reinstall Ubuntu and keeping all my data and directory structure?

Comment: The way to reinstall Ubuntu and keep all your data and directory structure is explained at [Reinstall Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I'll do it like you recommend because I'm short in time recently. I'm still a little bit unsatisfied (not your fault) because I curious about what's exactly happening and where the problem lies. Thinking back I accidentally left my laptop and it went on 0% battery forcefully shutting it down. I guess there is a connection - anyway thanks!

Comment: Just letting the laptop's battery power run down to 0% shouldn't be a major problem because the default ext4 filesystem in Ubuntu is a journaled filesystem that is resilient in situations like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, this generally happens when

1. some process is hindering the shutdown of computer, this problem is generally solved by reinstalling ubnutu, apt update, upgrade,auto driver install, or adding force shutdown to GRUB.
2. in other cases such as mine, i had two gpus driving my display at a time, an amd gpu and an nvidia gpu, both were showing on and running.
   Inbuilt driver for nvidia gpu which gets installed while installing ubuntu, sometimes keeps displaying the logo of ubuntu and freezes the shutdown.
   In that case, best shot is to uninstall that driver, or disable that driver.
   Seemingly unpopular way to disable that driver is to download run the executable file for device suitable nvidia driver from official nvidia drivers page.
   While intallation you have to exit X server mode and work in text based terminal, the new installation asks to give permission to create a file which disables the existing nvidia drivers, after that it does not matter if your driver installation is a success or not, since inbuilt nvidia support is disabled, the issue gets solved.

Comment: It was actually a hardware problem. We changed the motherboard without going into deeper analysis and now everything works fine